# No sound with audio jack

Tags: kernel, audio, upgrade, jack

I am using a **Debian** wheezy on Netbook **eeepc 1001px**

After last kernel update

When I plug the audio jack, I can here the electric charge but no
   sound when I remove it the internal speaker works

1. lspci

> ```
> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx DMI Bridge
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
> 00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
> 00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
> 00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
> 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
> 02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
> ```

2. alsamixer
   [image: alsamixer]

[image: F6 change card]

[image: When the audio jack is plugged]

[image: when unplugged]

start alsamixer default 
change card
when the audio jack is plugged in
when I remove it

3. etc/modprob.d

alsa-base-blacklist.conf

alsa-base.conf

```
    # autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet snd-seq ; : ; }
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet snd-emu10k1-synth ; : ; }
# Keep snd-pcsp from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
```

fbdev-blacklist.conf

radeon-kms.conf

Comment: Possibly a silly question... are you sure your headphones are working?

Comment: you were  right about it